# How to figure out which processes are deleting files from a specific directory?

Tags: io, auditd

I'm trying to figure out which processes are deleting files from a specific directory, so I want to set up and run `auditd` on my system.

I've set up the following rule in `audit.rules`:

`-w S unlink -S truncate -S ftruncate -a exit,always -k cache_deletion -w /home/myfolder/cache`

Then I type this to start the audit daemon:

`auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules -e 1`

But I get this error message:

`Error - nested rule files not supported`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, and how I can resolve this?

Also, what do I have to do to get the daemon running at startup?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end, I gave up on trying to do this because I was able to identify (through some other means) some code which causing the deletes to occur.

Comment: Just saw this. Downvoted because I found another way to do this? Some people need to get out more.

Answer (score 2):

That rule is trying to define two paths to audit, `-w S` and `-w /home/myfolder/cache`.  You can only use `-p and -k` options with `-w` too.

Try the following rule:

```
-a exit,always -S unlinkat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F dir=/home/myfolder/cache -F key=cache_deletion
```

...or for simplicity's sake:

```
-w /home/myfolder/cache -k cache_deletion -p wa
```

To start the service at startup:

```
/sbin/chkconfig auditd on
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, skohrs. Unfortunately, that didn't work - it returned the same error about 'nested rule files'.

Comment: Did you see my updated rule?  I had a typo.  Is this the only rule in /etc/audit/audit.rules?  In my testing, I had to use the 'unlinkat' system call to detect the file being removed.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now I get the following error: `The audit system is disabled`. I tried adding `-e 1` to the line in `/etc/audit/audit.trail`, but it still makes no difference.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi to enable auditing (with auditd running) just run `auditctl -e` (alone, by itself).

Comment: @voretaq7 No, that would fail. It needs a second parameter, the type of flag (0-silent, 1-print, 2-panic).