# How to check which processes are deleting files without using inotify or auditd?

Tags: monitoring, io, inotify, auditd

I'm trying to figure out which processes are deleting files from a specific directory on my CentOS server.

I looked at `inotify`, but all this does is to tell me how many file deletions are occurring; it does not tell me what process run by which user did the deletions, nor does it tell me when they happened.

I also tried `auditd`, but I [have had no luck in getting it set up on my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/433002/problems-getting-auditd-set-up-on-my-server).

Does anyone have any other tool they can suggest that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

auditd is the correct tool to be using here, man auditctl and set your rules correctly. Some good info: http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/rhel5-guide-i731.pdf